# Can MS OleDB driver for ORACLE do UPDATES

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, oledb

Has anyone used the MS OLEDB Driver to update an Oracle Database?

I have been coerced into (paid) doing some excel 2013 vba development.

We are trying to port a system from SQL server to ORACLE.

The queries are all working fine using the MS OLEdb driver for ORACLE. 
Here is the connection string...

```
Global Const ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data source=orclServer1;User ID=myReportingId;password=BigBoy;"
```

This works fine for queries. When you do updates, excel just wanders off into the weeds and goes catatonic.

I can use the ORACLE driver and it works fine. The problem is now all the spreadsheet users have to install the ORACLE CLIENT.

The MSDN page for the driver has some ominous things to say. Basically the driver is on its way out.  There is also a comment about only supporting static,read-only cursors, but its in a paragraph that is somewhat confusing. I wonder to myself is that a continuation of the discussion on joins, or a general statement?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

We have options, but thought I would reach out to this most excellent support community and see if anyone had a solution.

We are really trying to do a zero install type thing. So, .Net libraries, etc are all off the table. If there has to be an install, we will just require the ORCL client.

just sort of hoping there is some obscure option i can include in the connection string or set on the connection/command object.

for the sake of completeness, here is the vb code that I am using to attempt the update. Again, this works w/ the MS SQL SERVER oleDB provider and ORACLE's oleDB provider, just not the MS ORACLE oleDB driver.

```
Public Sub ExecuteUpdateQuery(qry_str As String)

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection

With cnn
    'constant defined above...
    .Open ConnectionString

    .Execute (qry_str)
    .Close
 End With
 End Sub
```

thanks...

greg

Comment: When you do an update is it slow, or it never returns? Does the Oracle driver work for exactly the same statement and data, and at the same time that he MS driver doesn't? An obvious cause of an update appearing to hang is an uncommitted transaction against the same data, so have you ruled that out?

Comment: thanks Alex. I am updating a single record in a table that has 1000 records. I let it 'run' for about an hour, so I am going to say that it never comes back.  Transactions are not an issue. And finally, yes, the ORACLE driver does the update in 0 seconds.  I really think the MS driver just doesnt do updates. Hard to believe...but that seems to be the case.